# Dumb insulation question

Tags: insulation, ceiling, attic

I need to install an attic floor in my workshop - currently the rafters are exposed.  I plan to use 3/4 plywood, then run faced insulation, then install a ceiling at a later date as time permits.  As I will tackle this project alone and the insulation will be exposed for an undetermined period of time, I was wondering if faced insulation can be glued to the underside of the attic floor as well as stapling to the 2x4 beams to keep insulation in place. (Roof trusses are engineered to accommodate attic floor, but had to eliminate that piece of the project for cost reasons.   Need to tackle it now as climate control in the winter is problematic).   Advice is welcome, eye rolls not so much.  :-)

Comment: if you have concerns about the insulation falling down, then staple plastic chicken fencing to the ceiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but glueing would be difficult. Most just lap the tabs on the FACED insulation and staple to the bottom of the 2x4’s...or staple to the sides of the 2x4’s.

The goal is to get all the insulation in straight (no puckering) and all edges and ends pushed together with no voids.

The blanket of insulation will expand slowly over time (4-6 hours) and help fill in all the voids. Make sure it doesn’t block the soffit vents.

BTW, wear a breather mask.